# PHP - basic strtotime from input

Tags: php, date, date-format, strtotime

I would like to edit current date of my posts which exists in database like; (type = datetime)

For instance #1;

```
2012-12-09 22:58:15
```

This is the post value (which I get successfully);

```
31/01/1980 08:20:00
```

When I use the following function to convert it to date I get '01/01/1970 01:00:00'

```
$date = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

I really don't understand why it keeps giving error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Neal: see the question again!

Comment: @Akam I am! I still do not see an error message there...

Comment: @Neal: `When I use the following function to convert it to date I get '01/01/1970 01:00:00'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

strtotime is failing, returning a boolean false, which is seen as (int)0 and translated to the unix epoch: midnight, jan 1, 1970

Read the nodes on the man page: http://php.net/strtotime for what formats it WILL accept/understand.

... then use http://php.net/date_create_from_format instead.

Answer (score 0):

From [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

You'll need to convert the date into `01/31/1980 08:20:00` or `31-01-1980 08:20:00` for strtotime to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is likely related to this note from the PHP manual on strtotime:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

You are sending d/m/y and PHP is disambiguating this as an American m/d/y time because of the slash separator in the date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this according to posted answers:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime(str_replace("/", "-", $_POST['date']));
echo $date->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
?>
```